# How to install a pod in a custom react native library?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, xcodeproj, react-native-linking

I'm trying to link a custom react native library which has a pod installed. When I install the pod in the custom library, xcworkspace is generated and I need to use the workspace there after, and I'm able to access the pods there. But, this custom library is linked as a xcodeproj to the ios project. So, it is unable to recognize the pod headers when it is linked.

Is there a way to link this custom library which has pods installed?

Comment: Please let me know your `react-native` version for this project.

Comment: The project is on 0.59.5